# Como hago para indicar 10 filas para un div con cssgrid

Tags: html, css, css-grid-layout

Tengo este html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">

        <!-- header -->
        <div class="header">

            <h1>Header</h1>
        </div>


        <!-- contenido -->
      <div class="items">

        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
        <input type="text" name="" id="">
      </div>
     


      <!-- footer -->
      <div class="footer">

        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div>
       
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y tengo este css:

```
.contenedor{

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(20vh,1fr));

    /* grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr); */

   grid-template-areas:"header header header header header header"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "items items items items items items"
                        "footer footer footer footer footer footer";
    gap: 1vh;
  
   
}

.header{
    grid-area: header;
    background-color: bisque;
}
.items{

    background-color: aqua;
   grid-area: items;
}
.footer{
    background-color: blue;
    grid-area: footer;
}
```

Pero me esta haciendo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo que quiero es un header arriba y un footer abajo y que los items o input abarquen 10 filas. Como logro eso?

Comment: exacto o más bien que los items abarquen 10 filas como esta especificado en el grid-template-areas:

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione con esta línea:

```
grid-auto-rows: minmax(20vh, auto);
```